# Routers urls with django rest framework 3.6 and django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.7, django-1.11

I have a django 1.7 with djangorestframework 3.3.2 site, and I'm migrating to django 1.11 with DRF 3.6. All things are working fine except routers with urls.

My Router:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'options', MicrositeViewSet)
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # '',
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

My viewsets:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

from microsites.permissions import AccountPermission
from microsites.models import Microsite
from microsites.serializers import SelfManagedMicrositeSerializer, MicrositeTestProfileSerializer


class MicrositeViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                       mixins.ListModelMixin,
                       mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                       viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing microsites.
    """
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AccountPermission,)

    serializer_class = SelfManagedMicrositeSerializer
    queryset = Microsite.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        microsite = request.microsite
        account = request.account

        queryset = Microsite.objects.filter(account=account)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        microsite = get_object_or_404(queryset, api_key=pk)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, microsite)
        microsite.pull()
        microsite.set_request_user(request.user)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            microsite,
            metadata=request.GET.get('metadata', False),
            categories=request.GET.get('categories', False),
        )
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)

        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        microsite = get_object_or_404(queryset, api_key=pk)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(microsite, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This code exactly as it is works with django 1.7 and DRF 3.2, but in django 1.11 and DRF 3.6 does not calls the urls of the router. Any clues? I thought that could be router.ulr with quotes, but says I don't have any urlpatterns in routers.

Comment: did you register your app in settings

Comment: @amrit Of course, this code works perfectly in django 1.7. I have not touched it.

Comment: can u show urls.py file

Comment: please show error stack

Comment: @BearBrown It does not show errors, just throw a 404 in the request, It seems it does not take the url's from the router.

Comment: What call gives a 404 ? Is that what you have when the GET the list ? A single item ? An update ? How do you query the server (curl ? browser ?) ?